# How to groupby columns by value and make json from them? Python3 Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset containing all the professors in Turkey. I need to change the shape of this data structure, but I couldn't find a solution. In this data, there is information about the university, faculty, department and title of approximately 44 thousand academicians.

`[ { "name": "XX", "title": "PROFESÖR", "university": "GEBZE TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "faculty": "MÜHENDİSLİK FAKÜLTESİ", "department": "BİLGİSAYAR MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ" }, { "name": "YY", "title": "PROFESÖR", "university": "GEBZE TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "faculty": "MÜHENDİSLİK FAKÜLTESİ", "department": "ELEKTRONİK MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ" } ]`

I have 44000 yields as above and I want to process them. For example, there are nearly 200 universities, I want to separate them.

`{ "universities": [ { "id": 1, "name": "GEBZE TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ", "faculties": [ { "id" : 1, "name": "MÜHENDİSLİK FAKÜLTESİ", "departments" : [ { "id" : 1, "name" : "ELEKTRONİK MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ", "academicians" : [ { "id" : 1, "name":"AA", "title" : "PROFESÖR" }, { "id" : 2, "name":"BB", "title" : "PROFESÖR" }, { "id" : 3, "name":"CC", "title" : "PROFESÖR" } ] }, { "id" : 2, "name" : "HARİTA MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ", "academicians" : [ { "id" : 1, "name":"DD", "title" : "PROFESÖR" }, { "id" : 2, "name":"EE", "title" : "PROFESÖR" } ] } ] } ] } ] }`

I want it as in the above format but I couldn't get it done. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.) get json datas

```
js_output = """{'universities': [{'id': 1,
   'name': 'GEBZE TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
   'faculties': [{'id': 1,
     'name': 'MÜHENDİSLİK FAKÜLTESİ',
     'departments': [{'id': 1,
       'name': 'ELEKTRONİK MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ',
       'academicians': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'AA', 'title': 'PROFESÖR'},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'BB', 'title': 'PROFESÖR'},
        {'id': 3, 'name': 'CC', 'title': 'PROFESÖR'}]},
      {'id': 2,
       'name': 'HARİTA MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ',
       'academicians': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'DD', 'title': 'PROFESÖR'},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'EE', 'title': 'PROFESÖR'}]}]}]}]}"""

js_input = """[{'name': 'XX',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'GEBZE TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'MÜHENDİSLİK FAKÜLTESİ',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ'},
 {'name': 'YY',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'GEBZE TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'MÜHENDİSLİK FAKÜLTESİ',
  'department': 'ELEKTRONİK MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ'}]"""
```

## 2.) set json normalize

```
# get record_path with json keys and get frame list
    
df_list = []                
def get_frames(l,j):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        df_list.append(pd.json_normalize(j, l[:i+1]))
        
records = ["universities", "faculties", "departments", "academicians"]
jdo = json.loads(js_output.replace("'",'"'))
get_frames(records, jdo)
```

## 3.) concatenate all frames

```
con = pd.DataFrame()
for df in df_list[:-1]: # because last item is dict and must be opened next step
    con = pd.concat([con, df.iloc[:,:-1]], axis=1)
con = pd.concat([con, df_list[-1]], axis=1)
```

## 4.) drop na because of example frame is output template

```
df = con.dropna().copy()
```

## 5.) design columns and match input keys for next concatenates

```
df.columns = [
    "uni_id",
    "university",
    "faculty_id",
    "faculty",
    "department_id",
    "department",
    "aca_id",
    "name",
    "title"
]
```

## 6.) refix id sections and join input frame with template

```
def input_join_to_get_desired_template(jdi):
    jdf = pd.DataFrame(jdi)
    con_df = pd.concat([df,jdf], ignore_index=True, sort=False)

    # enumerate ids with unique counts ↓ =================================================    
    unique_uni = list(con_df["university"].unique())
    unique_fac = list(con_df["faculty"].unique())
    unique_dep = list(con_df["department"].unique())

    con_df["uni_id"] = con_df["university"].apply(lambda x: unique_uni.index(x)+1)
    con_df["faculty_id"] = con_df["faculty"].apply(lambda x: unique_fac.index(x)+1)
    con_df["department_id"] = con_df["department"].apply(lambda x: unique_dep.index(x)+1)

    # set academicians indexes
    l = ["uni_id","faculty_id","department_id","aca_id"]
    con_df["aca_id"] = 1
    con_df["aca_id"] = con_df.groupby(l)["aca_id"].cumsum().to_frame()    
    # enumerate ids with unique counts ↑ =================================================

    return con_df

jd_input = json.loads(js_input.replace("'",'"'))
result_df = input_join_to_get_desired_template(jd_input)
result_df
```

## 7.) get other inputs and test

```
js_input_test = """[{'name': 'hl',
  'title': 'doc',
  'university': 'GEBZE ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'FAKÜLTESİ',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR BÖLÜMÜ'},
 {'name': 'hl',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'GEBZE ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'FAKÜLTESİ',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR BÖLÜMÜ'},
  {'name': 'yz',
  'title': 'yrddoc',
  'university': 'TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'other',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ'},
 {'name': 'zz',
  'title': 'doc',
  'university': 'TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'other',
  'department': 'ELEKTRONİK MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ'},
  {'name': 'hl',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'other',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ'},
 {'name': 'abc',
  'title': 'prof',
  'university': 'TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'other',
  'department': 'HARİTA MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ'},
  {'name': 'aaa',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'MÜHENDİSLİK',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR BÖLÜMÜ'},
 {'name': 'bbb',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'MÜHENDİSLİK',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR BÖLÜMÜ'},
  {'name': 'ccc',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'MÜHENDİSLİK',
  'department': 'BİLGİSAYAR BÖLÜMÜ'},
 {'name': 'ddd',
  'title': 'PROFESÖR',
  'university': 'ÜNİVERSİTESİ',
  'faculty': 'MÜHENDİSLİK FAKÜLTESİ',
  'department': 'ELEKTRONİK MÜHENDİSLİĞİ BÖLÜMÜ'}]"""
```

## 8.) and get results

```
jd_input = json.loads(js_input_test.replace("'",'"'))
result_df = input_join_to_get_desired_template(jd_input)
result_df
```